# SYCL DPC++ auto detect device

Tags: intel, intel-oneapi, sycl, intel-dpct

This question might be trivial, unfortunately I haven't found the answer I was looking for.

I used `dpct` migration tool to port some cuda code to Intel DPC++ and then I further optimized everything I needed and eventually got rid of everything related to `dpct` expect the super handy

```
dpct::get_current_device();
```

which basically solves all the previous pain I had to put compile options to select the appropriate device and control them with Makefiles and so on.

Is there any way to do this without using dpct ?
I had a look at how dpct does this ([here](https://github.com/oneapi-src/SYCLomatic/blob/be9a2455fda07ba43ae259b6c82e6eb2e2354c4f/clang/test/dpct/helper_files_ref/include/device.hpp#L475-L477)) but it looks pretty non-straightforward and it relies on other internal functions.

Is there any way to avoid this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally clear from your question whether you want to 1) grab a handle to your device or 2) select a device on which to run stuff, so I'll try to answer both. Note that `dpct::get_current_device()` isn't actually selecting a device, it's just returning the device which you have already selected earlier in your program.

1. Typically when using SYCL we start with a `sycl::queue`, which we use to submit kernels, memory copy operations etc. From a `sycl::queue` you can access your device with:

```cpp
sycl::device d = q.get_device();
```

2. But it seems like you may instead be asking for the simplest way to *select* a device. In this case, the simplest approach is to construct your queue with one of SYCL's provided device selectors:

```cpp
sycl::queue q{sycl::gpu_selector()};
sycl::queue q{sycl::cpu_selector()};
sycl::queue q{sycl::default_selector()};
```

Note that the last option (`sycl::default_selector()`) is probably what `dpct` is currently doing for you.

Comment: You're right, it was in fact doing `sycl::default_selector{}`. Your clarification helped me a lot, thanks!